# “qmake” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified

Tags: macos, qt5, omnet++

I'm trying to install the omnetpp simulator abut I was not able to use its graphic interface. To run it properly I have to install Qt5 which I did through homebrew. My Qt version is 5.15.0 and my MacOS is Catalina (10.15.5 (19F101)).

When running the `./configure` command to install omnetpp, I got the following error:

> “qmake” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.

*In summary I had problems with the omnetpp when trying to run the graphic interface Qt, then I've installed Qt5 and now I get an error telling me that qmake cannot be verified.*

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to circumvent this problem by opening System Preferences, Security & Privacy, General, and then allowing the file to be executed. When I ran make again the Qmake command ran without any warnings or windows popping up.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that this will come many times... It has something to do with the new security settings for MacOS Catalina.
I found another work-around, which worked very well for me. Go to Systems Preferences -> Security and Privacy -> Privacy. Scroll down the left menu to Developer Tools and allow Terminal to run software locally (tick the box).

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following command to "un-quarantine" your binary (assuming its path is `/usr/bin/qmake`):

```sh
xattr -w com.apple.quarantine "00c1;$(xattr -p com.apple.quarantine /usr/bin/qmake | cut -d";" -f2-4)" /usr/bin/qmake
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's website, you need to find qmake in the Finder, CTRL+click on it and press "Open". After that, qmake will be marked as an authorized app and you can run ./configure again.

I am a Windows user and could find the official Apple support page (https://support.apple.com/de-de/guide/mac-help/mh40616/mac) within a minute of googling, by the way.

Comment: Hi, this suggestion would work in the graphic mode, but not while running the make file for compiling the Qt on a mac.